Can a person with Iranian-German dual citizenship use her Iranian passport to apply for student visa in the Netherlands?
One of my Iranian friends has also obtained German citizenship. Now, she has two passports: an Iranian and a German.
However, she wants to just use her Iranian passport to apply for student visa from the Netherlands in order to start a PhD program there.
She is currently in Iran and does not want to use her german passport at all.
(1) Can the embassy understand that she has also a German passport? Can she be given the student visa of the Netherlands on her Iranian passport?
(2) Will she be able to enter the Netherlands with the visa on her Iranian passport, or will she have some problems upon entering the Netherlands?

Why? Is she aware of the rights which come with any EU citizenship within the EU?

I'm guessing in order to prevent the Iranian government from knowing about it.

Entering the Netherlands should be the easy part, at this point she can just ignore the visa and present her German passport, her other citizenship and any visa she may or may not have are completely irrelevant. Or does she also hope to obtain entry and exit stamps as Iranian citizens ordinarily would?

If the goal is to hide her German citizenship to Iranian authorities, a more common and perhaps easier tactic is to transit through a third country. There aren't many options for Iranian citizens but Turkey is an obvious one (and a major transit hub on the way to Europe). After reaching Turkey, everything else becomes irrelevant and she can just shows up at her Dutch university without any prior formality.

@Relaxed, if deceiving Iran is the goal, that would not provide Dutch stamps in her Iranian passport. She could claim to have been in Turkey the whole time, of course.

@o.m That's why I asked, the question does not mention stamps, depending on what her exact goal is, Turkey may be an option.

This plan sounds strange to me, and probably also to any visa or immigration official. Getting a residence permit is expensive, it requires documentation, it may not be granted, etc. The German citizenship, on the other hand, gives freedom of movement within the EU.

The Dutch student visa form asks about the nationality of the applicant. Omitting a second citizenship would be a lie on the official form.
A visa cannot be given if the German citizenship becomes known.

So any official who learns of the dual citizenship would be suspicious that something is wrong with some or all of the documents. If she convinces the official that both documents are genuine, she would be allowed in without an entry stamp on the Iranian passport.
I cannot answer about the risk of detection.

Why couldn't a visa be offered? It's completely unnecessary, would indeed look strange, and also seems unlikely to me but this answer seems to beg the question with absolutely no source or reasoning to back up its conclusion. It's also doubtful that a residence permit would be necessary and unclear to me whether the OP's plans to obtain one as well (although in the Netherlands, you would at least apply for it together with the visa).

@Relaxed, visa are issued to people, not to passports. The cases where EU citizens need to register are extremely limited, https://ind.nl/en/residence-permits/eu-eea-or-swiss-citizens/registering-with-the-ind-as-an-eu-eea-or-swiss-citizen#when-is-registering-with-the-ind-obligatory

Sure, I never said anything about visa being issued to passport and like I said, it also seems doubtful to me that the embassy would be willing to go along with the deception. On the other hand, you're just treating “not needed” and “impossible to get” as the same thing. I am sure the OP knows that a visa is not needed and he is not asking about that. Does it follow that it's impossible to get one? I suspect it might but just stating it without any justification isn't a very useful answer.

Incidentally, the thing about the registration is something completely different, just like a residence permit this is something you arrange after entering the country, why bring it up? Even EU citizens who need to register with the IND if they want to reside should not need a visa to enter the Netherlands.

@Relaxed, if you go to the Dutch immigration site, and look for the particulars of the case ("I am an EU citizen and want to stay in the Netherlands"), that is where it directs you. Nothing needed unless one is in the situation where a registration with the IND is required.

Yes that's obvious, I am very well aware of that, I have detailed why in many many answers on this site and expatriates, and already restated it in an earlier comment. So I don't need to go to the IND website and certainly not to go there to look at irrelevant things on stay and registration when we are talking about visas and entry. Again, why bother bringing it up? That is not even tangentially related to my point.

@Relaxed, because that is the answer the Dutch site gives to a German seeking visa information (i.e. "visa not required, IND registration in special cases"). The issue seems to be if the Netherlands can give an unnecessary visa into another passport if they know it is unnecessary from the data the applicant has given. Do you think they can?

I do not think they would, which is probably the most important thing for the OP. I don't know whether they can. I do know that the fact it's not needed does not by itself mean that it's forbidden for them to do it and an answer that confuses the two and does not even address the distinction completely useless in the context of this question.

The question never was whether it's required, there is absolutely no doubt about that and no reason to believe the OP doesn't know it. So quoting indirect evidence of that is a distraction and does not address the most important question (whether you could somehow convince the Dutch consulate to do it). I have asked you three time why you think a visa positively cannot be offered and you just repeat that's it's not needed. It's a non sequitur and begs the question.

@Relaxed, sorry about the late reply, I was mostly offline over the holiday. You are asking if the Dutch could be convinced to issue the unnecessary visa. I was assuming that the friend of the OP is telling the truth on the form (see my last sentence) and would get told no visa is required. A cover letter stating "I know I don't need it, please issue it anyway" is not what the OP is asking. The case here is the reverse image of questions we're getting from time to time about gaining EU citizenship while on a residence permit -- one legal status ends when the other starts.
